# On convergent sequences in locally convex topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Assume that a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of points of a locally convex topological vector space converges to zero. Is it always possible to find increasing number sequences $(n_k)_{k\in\omega}$ and $(m_k)_{k\in\omega}$ such that the sequence $(m_kx_{n_k})_{k\in\omega}$ still converges to zero?

**Added in Edit.** So we already know that this property (called *the Mackey convergence condition*) does not hold in any locally convex space. But we can ask another

**Problem.** Assume that a locally convex space $X$ admits an indexed family $(B_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\omega^\omega}$ of bounded sets such that (i) $B_\alpha\subset B_\beta$ for all $\alpha\le \beta$ in $\omega^\omega$ and (ii) each bounded subset $B\subset X$ is contained in some $B_\alpha$, $\alpha\in\omega^\omega$.

Does $X$ satisfy the Mackey convergence condition?

Answer (score 5):

This is satisfied for locally convex spaces with the so-called *Mackey convergence condition*, i.e., for every null sequence $x$ there is a bounded absolutely convex set $B$ such that $x$ tends to $0$ in the linear hull of $B$ endowed with the Minkowski functional of $B$ as a norm. This property was introduced by Grothendieck and is satisfied by metrizable spaces and virtually all *non-Banach* spaces arising in analysis (test function spaces $\mathscr D(\Omega)$, distributions $\mathscr D'(\Omega)$, spaces of germs of holorphic functions on compact sets, spaces of real analytic functions,...).

Answer (score 4):

Oh, sorry! I posed this question too quickly.

A simple example is the dual space $\ell_1=c_0^*$ to the Banach space $c_0$, endpowed with the weak$^*$ topology. The sequence $(e^*_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of coordinate functionals tends to zero, but for any increasing number sequences $(m_k)_{n\in\omega}$ and $(n_k)_{k\in\omega}$ the sequence $(m_ke^*_{n_k})_{k\in\omega}$ does not converge to zero on any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}\in c_0$ such that $x_{n_k}=\frac1{\sqrt{m_k}}$ for all $k\in\omega$.

Comment: By the Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem, for every Banach space $X$, $X^*$ contains a normalized, weak$^*$-null sequence, say $(x^*_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Then since for any increasing (natural) number sequences $(m_k)_k$, $(n_k)_k$, $(m_k x_{n_k}^*)_k$ is unbounded and not weak$^*$-null. So every dual Banach space with (any of its) weak$^*$ topologies is a counterexample.

Comment: A similar argument will show that any Banach space $X$ with its weak topology will have the property you want if and only if it is a Schur space.